# readline() returns a character at a time

Tags: python-3.x, readline

I am using Python 3.6.4 on Windows 10 with Fall Creators Update. I am attempting to read a XML file using the following code:

```
with open('file.xml', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in file.readline():
        do_something(line)
```

`readline()` is returning a single character on each call, not a complete line. The file was produced on Linux, is definitely encoded as UTF8, has nothing special such as a BOM at the beginning and has been verified with a hex dump to contain valid data. The line end is `0x0a` since it comes from Linux. I tried specifying `-1` as the argument to `readline()`, which should be the default, without any change in behavior. The file is very large (>240GB) but the problem is occurring at the start of the file.

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `'rt'` and not simply `r`?

Comment: I did originally with the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`readline()` will return a single line as a string (which you then iterate over). You should probably use `readlines()` instead, as this will give you a list of lines which your for-loop will iterate over, one line at a time.

Even better, and more efficient:

```
    for line in file:
        do_something(line)
```

Comment: I want a single line at a time because that is what is expected by the software I am calling.

Comment: Yes, your code will call do_something() with a single line at a time if you change readline() to readlines().

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but I'd recommend `for line in file` instead of `file.readlines()`. The former is an efficient iterator over the file, the latter returns a list in memory which is then iterated over. And considering OP's file is 240 GB, you wouldn't want to create a list from that, you'll run out of ram _fast_.

Comment: readlines() will return an array of lines which I would need to iterate over. In any case I am asking specifically why readline() is behaving in this manner.

Comment: @Jonathan `readline` returns a string, `readlines` returns a _list_ of strings. If you iterate over a string, you print characters. If you iterate over the list, you print strings. Is it not clear?

Comment: I want to get a single line at a time and pass it untouched and unexamined. I simply want to know why readline() returns a single character instead of a line as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Jonathan, you are misinterpreting something. readline() returns a full line, but your for-loop will iterate over the single characters in that returned string.
You can prove this by doing print(file.readline())

Comment: OK, I did mis-understand the situation. Changing to for line in file: gave me the desired behavior. To close this out can anyone suggest some good documentation on this. I have seen, and forgotten, hints that a file used in this manner acts as a generator, but have seen nothing authoritative.

Comment: _For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code_  See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: And if the tutorial isn't authoritative enough, you can look at the type of the file object returned by `open`, see that it's an `io.TextIOWrapper`, and go look at the documentation for [the `io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html): "IOBase (and its subclasses) supports the iterator protocol, meaning that an IOBase object can be iterated over yielding the lines in a stream."

Answer (score 2):

readline() returns a string representing a line in the file while readlines() returns a list, each item is a line. So it's clear that

```
for line in file.readline()
```

is iterating over a string, that's why you got a character

If you want to iterate over the file and avoid jamming your memory, try this:

```
line = '1'
while line:
    line = f.readline() 
    if !line:
        break
    do_something(line)
```

or:

```
line = f.readline()
while line:
    do_something(line)
    line = f.readline()
```

By the way, beautifulsoup is a useful package for xml phrasing.

Comment: Why would you recommend this approach over the approach proposed in the accepted answer?

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. First time to answer.